# unable to make a successful call from android using retrofit with csrf token

Tags: django, android-studio

I'm new to django and got struck with csrf tokens. I'm making a post request from android using retrofit to my django server which is using csrf protection. I had obtained the csrf token by making a get request first and then I'm passing this csrftoken from the body of POST request. However, my server is showing 'CSRF cookie not set' error. The server is responding well to the calls from POSTMAN but when I make calls from android, I get this error. I think there is some simple thing I'm missing, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: CSRF works by matching the CSRF token in the form parameters to the CSRF token in the cookie. How do make the calls from postman? Do you set a special header?

Comment: I'm first making a get request to my server and it is sending me the token back which is generated by "django.middleware.csrf.get_token" method and is sent to client in form of JSON. Then in the client side, I'm taking this token and putting it in the body of POST request to make further call.

Comment: CSRF is a possible vulnerability in **browsers**, not in arbitrary clients using an API. In principle, if your API is only consumed by Android apps and authorisation uses a token in the HTTP Autorization header rather than the session cookie, you don't need CSRF protection, because it's not possible to use a user's existing session to trick them to submit data to your server.

Comment: But if you include the token in your `X-CSRFToken` header, it should still work.

Comment: sorry, take that back, it only works in combination with the cookie. You need to set also the cookie in your POST request. Or set [`CSRF_USE_SESSIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#csrf-use-sessions) to `True` so you don't need to pass the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

*Session based authorization* is usually used in web-apps. In case of android apps which are backed by **API**.
So rather than you can do *Token Based Authorization* using **rest_framework** in *Django*.
In your settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'rest_framework',
 ]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # <-- And here
],
}
```

Now migrate the migrations to the database.

> python manage.py migrate

Run this command to generate token for the specific user.

```
python manage.py drf_create_token <username>
```

Now add this line to **urls.py**.

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
urlpatterns = [
#Some other urls.
path('api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'), 
]
```

Using this you can obtain token for any user by using its **username** & **password** by just passing them in **request body**.
So this will be our *protected api*. Add this class based view in your **views.py**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated,AllowAny  # <-- Here
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class DemoData(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def post(self, request):
    content = {'data': 'Hello, World!'}
    return Response(content)
```

Now pass a header with the api name as '*Authorization*' & value be like something '*Token 5a2b846d267f68be68185944935d1367c885f360*'

This is how we implement Token Authentication/Authorization in Django.

[For more info, click here to see official documentation.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)